# MySQL Queries - Selecting from 2 tables and if exists in the other check field

Tags: mysql

I am trying to pull products from a table called products, I also have a table called product_ranges.

```
products
--------
id
name
model

product_ranges
--------------
id
product_id
other_id

SELECT p.id 
FROM products As p 
LEFT JOIN product_ranges As pr ON (pr.product_id = p.id AND pr.other_id = 16)
```

This will select all products and include the product_ranges table columns too if the product exists in it but if it does exist in this table and the other_id does not equal 16 I don't want the product to be in the returned results but if the product doesn't exist at all in the other table I want it in the results still.

I am sure I have done this years ago but can't think of the SQL for it - if anyone knows the right query I would be grateful, thanks.

Comment: look at this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: Show sample data of what you want and don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN product_ranges pr ON pr.product_id = p.id
WHERE (pr.product_id IS NULL OR pr.other_id = 16)
```

Comment: thanks Michael but that doesn't quite work for what I want - it brings everything back where it doesn't exist in product_ranges, I want all that data back + if the product does exist in product_ranges, make sure other_id equals 16 in product_ranges

Comment: I updated my answer based on your comments. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Sorry Michael, think I owe you an apology! I noticed a few of my products in the product_ranges table that should not have been, this is why it looked like your query did not work for me, after removing the products and trying your code again I found it work perfectly for what I wanted, a much better approach I think than using IF like I did below, going to use yours instead! thanks